# How to remove an object from a position in a vector of shared_ptr and push back to the end?

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I want to create a method where I search for a specific object (this case a `Bar` object), inside a `vector`.
When I find that object bar in the `vector`, I should `push_back` that piece to the end of the `vector`.

I have 3 questions regarding this implementation... but I don't know if there is an easier way to do this.

This is my implementation:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Bar>> mBarVector;

//(...)

void Foo::pushBack(Bar& bar)
{
    for (auto& b : mBarVector)
    {
        if(*b == bar) // ERROR [1]
        {
            //mBarVector.erase(?) This position...?! How? [2]

            //mBarVector.push_back(bar); ERROR! [3]
        }
    }
}
```

1. How can I compare the the current iteration on the bar vector, with the reference to a bar from the method parameter?
2. Since I'm not using for(int i = 0, ...) how can I erase the position that I'm currently at?
3. After I remove the bar object from the vector, how can I insert a new one that is coming from a reference (to a shared_ptr)?

Comment: This is literally `find_if` + `rotate`.

Comment: Docs for [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate). Of course, if you don't need to maintain order of the other elements, you could just [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) the found element to the back.

Comment: for question 2, iterators have undefined behavior once you've removed an item from the vector.

Comment: Sounds more like a [stable_partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) to me

Comment: Would it work for you to simple `swap` the found pointer with the `back()` one?  That would reorder your vector a bit more but maybe that's OK?  If so it would be more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you want to do a deep comparison, then you're doing it correctly now, but you need to implement `operator==(const Bar&, const Bar&)`. If you want to do a shallow comparison, then you need to compare the addresses of the objects: `if(b.get() == &bar)`
2. You can't erase the *current* item in a range based loop, unless you separately keep track of the index or another iterator. A range based loop is simply not useful in this case.
3. A shared pointer to the object is in variable `b`. Simply copy that. Or, better for performance, move it.

> but I don't know if there is an easier way to do this.

There is.

First you need to find an iterator to the element to be moved. Simplest way to do that, depends again on whether you want shallow or deep comparison. For deep comparison, you can use `std::find`. You still need to have defined `operator==(const Bar&, const Bar&)`. For shallow comparison, you can use `std::find_if` with a comparison functor that compares the addresses.

Once you have the iterator, you can move the pointed element to the end using `std::rotate` if you want the order of other elements to stay the same. Simply rotate the vector from the found element to the end, so that the next element becomes the first one. Or, if the order is otherwise irrelevant, then you can do `std::swap` with the last element which is more efficient.

Edit: mkaes proposed `std::stable_partition` in a comment. It would also work and doesn't need a separate `find` call. You'll need a comparison functor even if you do use deep comparison. It'll work for multiple matches too, but that also means that it won't end early if one is found. You can use `std::partition`, if the order of other elements is irrelvant.

Comment: I would prefer `b.get()` instead of `&*b` (Bonus: handle `nullptr` and evil class with custom `operator&`)

Comment: Well, for vectors, the index is just `std::addressof(b) - mBarVector.data()`, but erasing would invalidate the range-based `for`'s iterators, so still not a good idea.